# Objective-C UIButton in UIView Hierarchy not animating

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiview, uibutton

I have a ScrollView with multiple Subviews and somewhere down there two UIButtons. They are not covered by a different UIView and they are perfectly visible.

The problem now is that the buttons are working, but they are not getting the "pressed" look like all other buttons.

Is there a possibility to trigger that "pressed" animation manually or is there another workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure for those buttons in the Attributes inspector the "Type" is set to "System"